# Why do joins give duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, join

I am very curious to know as to why the SQL joins gives duplicate rows. Consider I have an example of the data tables

```
|date     |source  |users
|24th June|organic |100
|24th June|Direct  |100
|23rd June|Organic |100
|22nd June|Paid    |100
```

If we have another table which is of a similar manner

```
|date     |source  |registrations
|24th June|paid    |10
|24th June|Direct  |30
|23rd June|Organic |50
|22nd June|Paid    |45
```

Let us call the above table as t2 and the first table as t1. When I perform a left join from t1 to t2 on the dates there are certain rows generated for the same. I wrote a query as

```
select t1.dates, t1.source,t1.users,t2.registrations
from t1
left join t2 on t1.dates = t2.dates
```

As per the above tables there shouldn't be any registration on 24th June for the source organic which is not a part of second table but it shows me. May I know what can be the reason as we don't have a primary key for the same. Also, can anyone guide me on the concept with some article as well?

Comment: Explain why "there shouldn't be any registration on 24th June for the source organic" with justification referencing authoritative documentation. Clearly "there should" be because there is. Maybe you mean "I don't want" or "I don't expect". You need to explain why you think that. Otherwise we can't address your misconceptions & we can only rewrite the manual or Q&A about how join works & we don't know what part you misunderstand. Similarly: What does " we don't have a primary key" mean? Why does it matter? PS Maybe you want date=date and source=source? PS Look at output using select \*.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging basic.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization. When you get a result that you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Asking for off-site resources is off-topic. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

An inner join is a *cross join* (all rows from one table combined with all rows from the other table) where all result rows that do not match the join condition have been filtered out. An outer join can add some NULL rows, but that is irrelevant for this discussion.

If `table1` is

| `col1` | `col2` |
| --- | --- |
| `1` | `val1` |
| `2` | `val2` |

and `table2` is

| `col3` | `col4` |
| --- | --- |
| `1` | `ups1` |
| `1` | `ups2` |

then the cross join contains these rows:

| `col1` | `col2` | `col3` | `col4` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `1` | `val1` | `1` | `ups1` |
| `1` | `val1` | `1` | `ups2` |
| `2` | `val2` | `1` | `ups1` |
| `2` | `val2` | `1` | `ups2` |

so if the join condition is `table1.col1 = table2.col1`, you end up with

| `col1` | `col2` | `col3` | `col4` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `1` | `val1` | `1` | `ups1` |
| `1` | `val1` | `1` | `ups2` |

That is, the row from `table1` appears twice, because it matches two rows in `table2`.

In your special case, there will be four (2 × 2) rows for `24th June`. I assume that you should add `source` to the join condition as well:

```
FROM t1
   JOIN t2 ON t1.dates = t2.dates AND t1.source = t2.source
```

Comment: So, if there is no primary key present in the table, then how do we join the tables? What can be the constraints as well on the same. Are we going to get duplicate rows and if yes, what are the necessary steps to be taken to avoid them

Comment: These questions seem to be unrelated to the original question...

Comment: Anyway, you always have a primary key on your tables. If you don't, you are lost.

Comment: I have edited the question, can you please help me now on the same?

Comment: I think you forgot a join condition, see my update.

Answer (score 0):

> As per the above tables there shouldn't be any registration on 24th June for the source organic which is not a part of second table but it shows me.

Why not? Your query is only joining on `date`, if you want to join on `date` and `source` you should specify that.

Joins are entirely specified by the query, they are not influenced by primary or foreign keys.